# What is the size of the beryllium in the Demon Core?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, laboratory-safety

The [Demon Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core) is covered by a hemisphere of beryllium. The Demon Core reaches criticality when the beryllium is completely closed. To achieve this, the size of the beryllium must be adjusted so that it becomes critical exactly when the beryllium is completely closed. So I consider the size of the beryllium to be very important information.

I have looked for this but could not find it, so please let me know. I would also like to know if there is a website or book that describes the Demon Core in detail!

Comment: Do you mean the beryllium hemisphere that was being adjusted during the second criticality accident (the one that killed Louis Slotin)?  The neutron reflectors Harry Daghlian was using were of different composition.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the second accident that Louis Slotin.